# Import JSON key value into pandas dataframe error

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm trying to capture a json and put it on a json dataframe. The obtained json has the following format:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://was-p.bcnet.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata$metadata#_CotacaoDolarPeriodo(cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao)","value":[{"cotacaoCompra":1.80030,"cotacaoVenda":1.80110,"dataHoraCotacao":"2000-01-03 19:43:00.0"},{"cotacaoCompra":1.83290,"cotacaoVenda":1.83370,"dataHoraCotacao":"2000-01-04 19:13:00.0"},{"cotacaoCompra":1.85360,"cotacaoVenda":1.85440,"dataHoraCotacao":"2000-01-05 19:11:00.0"},...{"cotacaoCompra":1.83840,"cotacaoVenda":1.83920,"dataHoraCotacao":"2000-05-25 19:14:00.0"}]}
```

However, I want to get only his 'value' key in the following format in dataframe pandas:

| cotacaoCompra | cotacaoVenda | dataHoraCotacao |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.80030 | 1.80110 | 2000-01-03 19:43:00.0 |
| 1.83290 | 1.83370 | 2000-01-04 19:13:00.0 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: |
| 1.83840 | 1.83920 | 2000-05-25 19:14:00.0 |

But when I run the code, the following error appears: ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>

Here is the code I am using:

```
url = 'https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata/CotacaoDolarPeriodo(dataInicial=@dataInicial,dataFinalCotacao=@dataFinalCotacao)?@dataInicial=%2701-01-2000%27&@dataFinalCotacao=%2711-01-2020%27&$top=100&$format=json&$select=cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
data = resp.json()
json.dumps(data['value'])[1:-1]
json.loads(json.dumps(data['value']))
df = pd.read_json(data)
df.head()
```

Can you help me move json to the dataframe in the format above?

Comment: Try: `pd.DataFrame(data['value'])`

Comment: Wow. Thats work like a charm! Thanks very much

Comment: so how is it that adding ['value'] directs Pandas to the correct place to begin in the data?